# Sum one value in a multidimensional associative array based on matching two other values (php)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an associative array that is essentially static dummy data for a mock-up that is standing in for a database. I am trying to replicate what GROUPBY YEAR AND TitleText would do in MySQL and I can make it work on one field - either TitleText or YEAR using array_reduce but I can't figure out how to do it on both fields together. I need one row for each YEAR and TitleText combination that sums the units. Here is the array:

```
$monthly_sales = [
        [
        'XML_KEY' => '9992', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(7)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(7)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => '1984', 
        'units' => 15 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9990', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(7)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(7)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => 'Animal Farm', 
        'units' => 7 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9991', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(7)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(7)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => 'Keep the Aspidistra Flying', 
        'units' => 5 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9990', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(6)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(6)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => 'Animal Farm', 
        'units' => 6 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9991', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(6)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(6)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => 
        'Keep the Aspidistra Flying', 
        'units' => 6 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9992', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(6)["Month"],
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(6)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => '1984', 
        'units' => 2  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9991', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(5)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(5)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => 'Keep the Aspidistra Flying', 
        'units' => 5  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9992', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(5)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(5)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => '1984', 
        'units' => 3 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9990', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(5)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(5)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => 'Animal Farm', 
        'units' => 3  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9990', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(4)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(4)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => 'Animal Farm', 
        'units' => 4  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9991', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(4)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(4)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => 'Keep the Aspidistra Flying', 
        'units' => 4  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9992', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(4)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(4)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => '1984', 
        'units' => 3  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9990', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(3)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(3)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => 'Animal Farm', 
        'units' => 10 
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9992', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(3)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(3)["Year"],
        'TitleText' => '1984', 
        'units' => 4  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9991', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(3)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(3)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => 'Keep the Aspidistra Flying', 
        'units' => 1  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9990', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(1)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(1)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => 'Animal Farm', 
        'units' => 9  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9991', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(1)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(1)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => 'Keep the Aspidistra Flying', 
        'units' => 3  
        ], [ 
        'XML_KEY' => '9992', 
        'MONTH' => get_relative_date(1)["Month"], 
        'YEAR' => get_relative_date(1)["Year"], 
        'TitleText' => '1984', 
        'units' => 1  
        ]
    ];
```

Here is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [YEAR] => 2014
            [TitleText] => 1984
            [units] => 27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [YEAR] => 2014
            [TitleText] => Animal Farm
            [units] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [YEAR] => 2014
            [TitleText] => Keep the Aspidistra Flying
            [units] => 21
        )
    [3] => Array
        (

            [YEAR] => 2015
            [TitleText] => 1984
            [units] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [TitleText] => Animal Farm
            [units] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [TitleText] => Keep the Aspidistra Flying
            [units] => 3
        )
)
```

I greatly appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write your array like the outpout that you want is better,  I suppose that you're array $monthly_sales is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [YEAR] => 2014
            [TitleText] => 1984
            [units] => 27
            [XML_KEY] => 9992
            [MONTH] => 10
               ) 
)
```

Code:

```
    $info = array();
    $final = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($monthly_sales); $i++) {
    $year = $monthly_sales[$i]['YEAR'];
    $title = $monthly_sales[$i]['TitleText'];

    $info[$year][$title] += $monthly_sales[$i]['units'];
    }

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($info as $year => $data) {
      foreach($data as $title => $units) {
        $final[$i]['Year'] = $year;
        $final[$i]['TitleText'] = $title;
        $final[$i]['units'] = $units;
        $i++;
      }
    }

    print_r($final);
```

Comment: Thanks - this isn't the only place where I use this array so I'd rather not redo it unless there is no other choice. Surely it shouldn't matter which order the elements are in... I tried your code and rather than returning six elements - one for each year/title combo I only got two each year but only the last title in the array for that year - this is exactly what has happened to me each way I try it too - I can't figure out how to get it to create a distinct record for each combination.

Comment: please edit your post with the output of print_r($monthly_sales);

Comment: @Regina McCreary I update the code, check it now, but if better if you write the output of print_r($monthly_sales);